# How to find and replace , same but different words in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

So i have 2 big list of md5 text file
One of them are in its encrypted format 
And one more are with its decrypted format but some are missing
The format is (Example)

1st file:

```
Md5 = 
ea32sd
23fr24r
dada45r
```

2st file:

```
Md5:meanings = 
23fr24r:yo
(Missing)
dada45r:hey
```

So what i wanna do is , to find only the same md5 and replace it so that the meaning is the only one left

Its like

```
23fr24r = 23fr24r:yoo
dada45r = dada45r:hey
```

Becomes

```
yoo
Hey
```

Im sorry if you dont get my points cause english is not my first language

Comment: That is not a job for notepad++. Write a script to do that.

Comment: Which script ? Any tips ?

Comment: Anyone you're confident with, ie. shell, batch, perl, python ...

Comment: well i currently cant write a script :/

Answer (score 0):

Script could solve this problem quite easily. However, you can actually do that in Notepad++ by using the powerful replacement function on the second file.

Replacement 1 (regular expression): `^(?!Md5)(\w+):` => `\1 = \1:`

Replacement 2 (regular expression): `^(?!(?!Md5).*=).*$` => (empty)

Replacement 3 (Extend) : `\n\r` => (empty)

That will do the trick.